# C# filling list in the background

Tags: c#, list, listview, streamreader

I have a log file with an huge amount of entries (100.000 and more). I read every line with a Streamreader an save it in a list. A listview gets the list and displays it.

My problem is that it takes to long to read the whole file and store it in a list.

Is there a possibility to fill the list gradually in the background while the application is running? Or is there another way to read and load big files?

Comment: You can use thread for background tasks.

Comment: What version of .net are you targeting? The best solution depends on the answer to that.

Comment: The .NET Framework is version 4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Use background worker in .net, it helps also to show running percentage,
For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
       private BackgroundWorker _myWorker;
       
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           _myWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
           _myWorker.DoWork += _myWorker_DoWork;
           _myWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += _myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
           _myWorker.ProgressChanged += _myWorker_ProgressChanged;
       }

       private void _myWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           //Here you can calculate procetage of reading linses from your file
       }

       private void _myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
       {
           //Reading from file finished:
       }

       private void _myWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       {
           var counter = 0;
           var file =new System.IO.StreamReader("<file path>");

           string line;
           while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
               //Adding "line" value to listView etc.
               counter++;
               var percentage = yourCalculationMethos();
               _myWorker.ReportProgress(percentage);
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and do it with threads. Here is an explanation:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/using-threads-and-threading